# Gatsby createResolvers with runQuery returning error

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I'm following the examples from the Gatsby documentation but getting an error when trying to use the explorer view of the schema:

```
exports.createResolvers = ({ createResolvers }) => {
  const resolvers = {
    Product: {
      categorySlug: {
        type: ["Category"],
        resolve(source, args, context, info) {
          return context.nodeModel.runQuery({
            query: { 
              filter: { 
                name: { eq: source.category } 
              } 
            },
            type: "Category",
            firstOnly: true,
          })
        },
      },
    },
  }

  createResolvers(resolvers)
}
```

Error in explorer:

```
"message": "Field \"categorySlug\" of type \"[Category]\" must have a selection of subfields. Did you mean \"categorySlug { ... }\"?",
```